# Why isn't my plm model defaulting automatically to plm::lag?

Tags: r, lag, plm

I've found that sometimes my `plm` regressions in R (package `plm`) don't default automatically to the use of `plm::lag`, what has caused me a lot of trouble. I've searched for the reasons for this in other posts, but I haven't found anything. Does anyone know how to correct this without having to write `plm::lag` in every regression?

Just a simple example in code:

```r
library(plm)

model <- plm (GDP ~ plm::lag(expenses), data=dd, effect='twoways',...)
```

Comment: Do you have dplyr loaded? It clobbers lag with its own incompatible lag.  Make sure dplyr is NOT loaded.  If you need to load dplyr and are using R 3.6 or later load it like this: library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))

Comment: Yes, I was! Thank you very much, it was very helpful!

Comment: Will this exclude the filter function also?

Comment: Yes. It also clobbers filter.  Use dplyr::lag and dplyr::filter if you need to use them in dplyr pipelines.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491196/lag-from-pglm-seems-to-bug-lag-from-stats/70491501#70491501