# lag() from pglm seems to bug lag() from stats

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

As the title says. After I load `pglm`, `lag` stops to work properly.

```
library(pglm)

c(1,2,3,4) %>% lag()
```

the object is converted into a time series and is not compatible anymore with tibbles.

Even unloading `pglm`, the dependency for `lag` is still effective.

A solution could be to actually never load `pglm`, but then if I have a `lag(x)` in the formula

```
pglm:pglm(
family= poisson,
y ~ lag(x),
model = "within", index="id",
data = db
)
```

The algorithm cannot converge into an estimate. For some reasons this happens even forcing `stats::lag(x)`. The fun thing is that, instead, if `pglm` is loaded, `y ~ lag(x)` works properly as `y ~ stats:lag(x)`.

This is the only case where it works, tho! The only other thing that I think of is that outside formulas, `dplyr::lag` is the culprit for the conflict.

I don't know how to optimise the workflow, have you suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dplyr is the culprit here.  plm (used by pglm) defines a `lag` method `lag.pseries` which is dispatched by the generic `lag` in stats.  Other packages, such as plm and others, supply methods for the generic `lag`; however, dplyr clobbers the generic with its own non-generic `lag` so all packages that use `lag` then fail.  If you need to have dplyr loaded at the same time as pglm load dplyr excluding `lag` and if you need to use dplyr's `lag` use `dplyr::lag` .  Ditto for `filter`.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
```